# PHP Regex - URL - link to a file

Tags: php, regex, url

How can I identify via preg_match that a string containing a URL is actually pointing to a file and not to a valid page. For example:

```
www.example.com/a.png
www.example.com/a/b/c/d.mp4
www.example.com/e/f/h.xls
```

If I just do an explode on "." and check last index, it will not work. Also, I don't have the complete list of possible extensions and want to write something generic.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not work? exploding on `.` seems to be nice

Comment: it will pick .com also which is a valid page and not a link to a file...

Comment: by doing an array_pop it will get you the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\/.+\.(?!php|php5)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}
```

(php and php5 are examples for blacklist here)

Or

explode on `.` and do an array_pop on it.

I suggest to use a whitelist instead of blacklist. Add only allowed extensions.